# IsNumeric on VS2012 (windows forms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am using the following code:

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then
    not important code
Else
    MsgBox("O campo minutos só pode conter números!")
End If
```

Basically what I need is to check if the data inserted on the textbox is only numbers or not, when I insert letters or special characters like # or $ it works just fine and the error pops up, but if I enter +6 it goes through to the code.

Is this normal? If so is there a way to give the error even when it has a + or -? When I use *, / or = it also pops-up the error.

Comment: unary plus and minus are usually allowed for numbers. There isn't a unary `*`, `/` or `=` in most languages. Do you want to only allow *digits*?

Comment: Yes Damien, i would like to allow only digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, i tried you suggestions but somehow they didnt work :S

Managed to solve the problem like this:

```
For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
    If c = "+" Or c = "-" Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) And i = 0 Then
    not important code
Else
    MsgBox("O campo minutos só pode conter números!")
End If
```

Again thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you only want to keep numbers chars (no ".", ",", ...)
Using `Where()` and VB's lamba expression. This selects then count any caracter not in the digits string, then checks if the count is equal to zero.

```
If IsNumeric(myString.Where(Function(c) Not "0123456789".Contains(c)).Count() = 0) Then
    not important code
Else
    MsgBox("O campo minutos só pode conter números!")
End If
```

Better, using `Any()` instead of `Where().Count()`

```
If IsNumeric(Not myString.Any(Function(c) Not "0123456789".Contains(c))) Then
    not important code
Else
    MsgBox("O campo minutos só pode conter números!")
End If
```

This could probably be done with a regular expression too.

Answer (score 1):

IsNumeric() casts a pretty big net.  It also considers currency values to be numbers.  Well, they certainly are to an accountant.

If you want to make it more restrictive then use a conversion method that's more specific to the type of number you like.  Like Double.TryParse().

Answer (score 1):

Just incase you want to have it look a bit better try

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) And TextBox2.Text.Contains("+") or Textbox2.Text.Contains("-")        
Then
    not important code
Else
MsgBox("O campo minutos só pode conter números!")
End If
```

PS: Glad you figured it out hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the KeyDown event of your text control will help?

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyValue
        Case Keys.NumPad0 To Keys.NumPad9
            ' code here for keys 0 through 9 from Keypad
        Case Keys.D0 To Keys.D9
            ' code here for keys 0 through 9 from top of keyborad

        Case Keys.Multiply, Keys.Divide, Keys.Add
            ' code here gor other characters like * / + etc.
        Case Else
            ' Code here for all other keys, supress key if needed
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif